# PlatformEffect in .NET Standard lib doesn't get resolved

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, effect, .net-standard-2.0

I have implemented a Xamarin.Forms effect and spiked i successfully but I now need to create a proper NugGet package to use it as a component in my projects.

I added a .NET Standard lib for the `RoutedEffect` implementation. Then created three platform-specific lib projects for iOS, Android and UWP. To try everything out I then created a new Xamarin.Forms app with a .NET Standard "common" lib that references the `RoutedEffect`´s .NET Standard lib. Finally, from the iOS app I reference both the RoutedEffect's lib and the (iOS) `PlatformEffect` implementation lib.

The problem is that the `PlatformEffect` never gets instantiated. I tried resolving it from the .NET Standard common lib, just to see what's going on, and I just get back a `NullEffect`. For sake of sanity I then tried moving the code for the iOS PlatformEffect from its iOS lib into the iOS app. This works. But I have no idea why it won't work when implemented in the iOS lib, when referenced from the iOS app.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a bit embarrasing, and an example why you shouldn't code late in the night I guess. :-/

After a good night's sleep I realized the `PlatformEffect` lib, which consist of one effect only, was only referenced from the iOS project but none of the lib's types was actually referenced and, so, the .NET linker won't link the lib.

Just adding a reference to the platform `Effect` type solved the problem and it works fine.

Please move on ... :-)